# Update same column with multiple values at different positions using Overlay function in Postgres

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-update, overlay

I have two columns in table `test` as below. I want to update 2nd position in message with 'K' and 4th position as 'N' where `id = 1` using Overlay function. I am able to update 2nd position as per below query but unable to find solution for 4th position.

Could you please provide me some guidance? Thank you.

Table `test`

```
    id | message
    ------------
    1  | ABCD
    2  | PQRS
```

I wrote below query:

```
update test
set message = overlay(message placing 'K' from 2 for 1)
where id = 1
```

I got reference from [Postgres String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with `overlay()`, you need to call it twice:

```
overlay(overlay('ABCD' placing 'K' from 2 for 1) placing 'N' from 4 for 1)
```

You could also use `substring()`:

```
substring(message, 1, 1) || 'K' || substr(message, 3, 1) || 'N'
```

Or, if `message` can contain more than 4 characters:

```
substring(message, 1, 1) || 'K' || substr(message, 3, 1) || 'N' || substr(message, 5)
```

Finally: a neater option (although probably less efficient) uses a regex:

```
regexp_replace(message, '^(.)(?:.)(.)(?:.)', '\1K\2N')
```